# How to find primary id on the basis of combine data of two or more columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the primary id of the data row on the basis on combine data of two columns. 
I'm using C# and i have combine data of the two columns Product_Name and Packing and i want to get the Product_ID on the the basis of combine data of the product Like Select Product_ID from Products Where Something Like '%Tang 200 g%' 
The Problem is that what  i wrote in the place of 'Something'?

```
Produt_ID  | Product_Name | Packing
   1           Tang          200 g
   2           Soap           50 g


Select Product ID from Products Where Combine(Product_Name,' ',Packing) Like '%Tang 200 g%'
```

but it does not give the correct id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using concat()

```
Select Product ID 
from Products Where concat(Product_Name,' ',Packing) Like '%Tang 200 g%'
```

or use like   AND like

```
Select Product ID 
from Products Where Product_Name '%Tang% 
AND Packing like'%200 g%'
```